# Troubleshooting Infinite loop in Sql Query Notification in C# winforms

Tags: c#, sql

I am creating a an application which has a Sql Query Notification but i'ved encountered a problem .. The System is kept on looping that goes onto infinite loop.The Query that i'ved used is in Stored Procedures and I'ved used 7 tables in my Query.
What seems to be the problem of my query or my application ?
Kindly Help me to resolved this thanks :)
I'll post my codes here
This is the Stored Procedures i am using

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[INVENTORYLOG_VIEW]
AS
    BEGIN
    SELECT     
     ACCOUNT.Emp_Fname + ' ' + ACCOUNT.Emp_Lname AS [USERS],
     INVENTORYLOG.ACTIVITYDATE AS [ACTIVITY DATE], 
     INVENTORYLOGDETAILS.ACTIVITYTIME AS [ACTIVITY TIME],
     INVENTORYLOGDETAILS.LOG_ACTION AS [USER LOG], 
     CATEGORY.CATEGORY_NAME, 
     BRAND.Brand_Name AS BRAND, 
     PRODUCTDESCRIPTION.DESCRIPTION_TYPE, 
     COLOR.Color_Name AS [COLOR NAME], 
     SIZES.SIZE, 
     INVENTORY.QUANTITY_ON_HAND AS [CURRENT QTY], 
     INVENTORYLOGDETAILS.QUANTITY_LOG_ACTION AS [USER LOG QTY]
FROM         
dbo.ACCOUNT INNER JOIN
dbo.INVENTORYLOG ON dbo.ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_ID = dbo.INVENTORYLOG.Account_Id INNER JOIN
dbo.INVENTORYLOGDETAILS ON dbo.INVENTORYLOG.INVENTORYLOGID = dbo.INVENTORYLOGDETAILS.INVENTORYLOGID INNER JOIN
dbo.INVENTORY ON dbo.INVENTORYLOGDETAILS.INVENTORY_ID = dbo.INVENTORY.INVENTORY_ID INNER JOIN
dbo.PRODUCT_DTL ON dbo.INVENTORY.PRODUCT_DTL_ID = dbo.PRODUCT_DTL.PRODUCT_DTL_ID INNER JOIN
dbo.COLOR ON dbo.PRODUCT_DTL.COLOR_ID = dbo.COLOR.Color_Id INNER JOIN
dbo.BRAND ON dbo.PRODUCT_DTL.BRAND_ID = dbo.BRAND.Brand_Id INNER JOIN
dbo.CATEGORY ON dbo.PRODUCT_DTL.CATEGORY_ID = dbo.CATEGORY.CATEGORY_ID INNER JOIN
dbo.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION ON dbo.PRODUCT_DTL.DESCRIPTION_ID = dbo.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION.DESCRIPTION_ID INNER JOIN
dbo.SIZES ON dbo.PRODUCT_DTL.SIZE_ID = dbo.SIZES.SIZE_ID
END
```

And This is the Codes in my application

```
        string connect;
        String connection;
        private SqlConnection cons = null;
        private SqlCommand command = null;
        private DataSet myDataSet = null;
        public Inventory_InventoryLog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.gridView1.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = false;
            this.gridView1.ScrollStyle = ScrollStyleFlags.LiveHorzScroll | ScrollStyleFlags.LiveVertScroll;
            ConnectionString access = new ConnectionString();
            connection = access.AccessConnection(connect).ToString();

            // Sql Notifications Automatic
            EnoughPermission();
        }

        public bool EnoughPermission()
        {
            SqlClientPermission perm = new SqlClientPermission(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);
            try
            {
                perm.Demand();
                MessageBox.Show(""+perm);
                return true;
            }
            catch(System.Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        private void GetActivateData()
        {
            try
            {
                //String query = "SELECT [USER], [ACTIVITY DATE], [ACTIVITY TIME], [USER LOG], CATEGORY_NAME, Brand_Name, DESCRIPTION_TYPE, Color_Name, SIZE, [ CURRENT QTY], [USER LOG QTY] FROM INVENTORY_INVENTORY_LOG_DETAILS";
                SqlDependency.Stop(connection);
                SqlDependency.Start(connection);
                if (cons == null)
                  cons = new SqlConnection(connection);
                if (command == null)
                {
                    command = new SqlCommand("dbo.INVENTORYLOG_VIEW", cons);
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                }
                if (myDataSet == null)
                    myDataSet = new DataSet();
                GetActualData();
            }
            catch (Exception p)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(""+p);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Being called");
        }
        private void GetActualData()
        {
            myDataSet.Clear();
            command.Notification = null;
            SqlDependency dependecy = new SqlDependency(command);
            dependecy.OnChange +=new OnChangeEventHandler(dependecy_OnChange);
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                adapter.Fill(myDataSet, "dbo.ACCOUNT, dbo.INVENTORYLOG, dbo.INVENTORYLOGDETAILS, dbo.INVENTORY, dbo.PRODUCT_DTL,dbo.COLOR,dbo.BRAND,dbo.CATEGORY,dbo.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, dbo.SIZES");
                gridControl1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["dbo.ACCOUNT, dbo.INVENTORYLOG, dbo.INVENTORYLOGDETAILS, dbo.INVENTORY, dbo.PRODUCT_DTL,dbo.COLOR,dbo.BRAND,dbo.CATEGORY,dbo.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, dbo.SIZES"];
                gridView1.BestFitColumns();
                gridView1.BestFitMaxRowCount = 10;
            }

        }

        delegate void UIDelegate();
        public void dependecy_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                UIDelegate uidel = new UIDelegate(RefreshDatas);
                this.Invoke(uidel, null);
                SqlDependency dependency = (SqlDependency)sender;
                dependency.OnChange -= dependecy_OnChange;
            }
            catch (Exception es)
            {
             //   XtraMessageBox.Show(es.Message);
            }
        }
        public void RefreshDatas()
        { 
            ////////////////////////
            //---------------------------------------   NOTIFICATION INSERTS HERE ----------------------------------- //////
            label1.Text = "Changes Happened";
            GetActualData();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        /// //--------------------------------------------------------  SQL NOTIFICATION ------------------------------------
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args"></param>


        public SqlConnection ConnectionStringMethod()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
            con.Open();
            return con;
        }
        private void Inventory_InventoryLog_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetActivateData();           
        }
```

I really need answers to these problem please do help me...
Thanks :)

Comment: Please post the most relevant code only..It will be difficult to read entire code..

Answer (score 1):

You call GetActualData() in RefreshDatas() which in turn gets called by an onchange delegate which is triggered in GetActiveData().

GetActiveData() calls GetActualData() again, hence the loop.

To 'fix' it, you should remove the onchange delegate from GetActualData and move it to GetActivateData.

like so:

```
private void GetActivateData()
        {
            try
            {
                //String query = "SELECT [USER], [ACTIVITY DATE], [ACTIVITY TIME], [USER LOG], CATEGORY_NAME, Brand_Name, DESCRIPTION_TYPE, Color_Name, SIZE, [ CURRENT QTY], [USER LOG QTY] FROM INVENTORY_INVENTORY_LOG_DETAILS";
                SqlDependency.Stop(connection);
                SqlDependency.Start(connection);
                if (cons == null)
                  cons = new SqlConnection(connection);
                if (command == null)
                {
                    command = new SqlCommand("dbo.INVENTORYLOG_VIEW", cons);
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                }
                if (myDataSet == null)
                    myDataSet = new DataSet();

            SqlDependency dependecy = new SqlDependency(command);
            dependecy.OnChange +=new OnChangeEventHandler(dependecy_OnChange);


                GetActualData();
            }
            catch (Exception p)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(""+p);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Being called");
        }
        private void GetActualData()
        {
            myDataSet.Clear();
            command.Notification = null;
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                adapter.Fill(myDataSet, "dbo.ACCOUNT, dbo.INVENTORYLOG, dbo.INVENTORYLOGDETAILS, dbo.INVENTORY, dbo.PRODUCT_DTL,dbo.COLOR,dbo.BRAND,dbo.CATEGORY,dbo.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, dbo.SIZES");
                gridControl1.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables["dbo.ACCOUNT, dbo.INVENTORYLOG, dbo.INVENTORYLOGDETAILS, dbo.INVENTORY, dbo.PRODUCT_DTL,dbo.COLOR,dbo.BRAND,dbo.CATEGORY,dbo.PRODUCTDESCRIPTION, dbo.SIZES"];
                gridView1.BestFitColumns();
                gridView1.BestFitMaxRowCount = 10;
            }

        }
```

Comment: so what should i do Elger?
Any solution please?

Comment: Elger
I've tried to remove the GetActiveData() in RefreshDatas() whenever i inserted data it doesn't appear or updates automatically on the grid..

Comment: Mr. elger thanks for the solution now it is not infinite but the thing that i wanted is does met..
What i want is that whenever the i inserted data it would automatically updates on the grid but it does not automatically 
updates..

a while ago when it is on the infinite state it automatically updates data but now that is not infinite it does not automatically updates..
what seems to be the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's too difficult to get a clear view of what you're trying to achieve. I guess it's best to sit down with a senior programmer to fix the problem. Good luck.

Comment: don't you think the problem is in my QUery?

Comment: No the problem seems to be that the SqlDependency to refresh your data isn't working/firing. Try to debug if it's firing or not. If you don't know how to do that, then please seek help from an experienced programmer that sits next to you. Everybody has to learn, I respect that, but I cannot help you any further.